# MariaDB PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm doing a project for college. Exactly the SQL database. In project I must make 2 procedures but every time I try add procedure it not work (Procedure is not added and can't be executed or called).  I am using MariaDB.

Code procedure:

```
delimiter //
USE kwiaciarnia
CREATE PROCEDURE  klienci_nie_obslugiwani (IN p1 varchar(30))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM klienci, nie_obslugiwany
WHERE klienci.id_klienta = nie_obslugiwany.klienci_id_klienta AND nie_obslugiwany.`status`= p1;
END
delimiter ;
```

Code table klienci

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `klienci` (
  `id_klienta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imie` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `nazwisko` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `PESEL` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `adres` tinytext COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefon` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_klienta`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PESEL_UNIQUE` (`PESEL`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;

-- Zrzucanie danych dla tabeli kwiaciarnia.klienci: ~39 rows (około)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `klienci` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `klienci` (`id_klienta`, `imie`, `nazwisko`, `PESEL`, `adres`, `email`, `telefon`) VALUES
    (1, 'Apolonia', 'Kaczmarek', '79090913745', 'ul. Kasprzaka Marcina 110 51-676 Wrocław', 'ApoloniaKaczmarek@armyspy.com', '142563574'),
    (2, 'Bonifacy ', 'Kowalski', '94061013178', 'ul. Limanowskiego Bolesława 64 02-943 Warszawa', 'BonifacyKowalski@teleworm.us', '536467567'),
    (3, 'Gabrysz', 'Tomaszewski', '75030121678', 'ul. Batorego Stefana 109 42-400 Zawiercie', 'GabryszTomaszewski@dayrep.com', '342534563'),
    (4, 'Walentyna', 'Kamińska', '84012216309', 'ul. Gdańska 132 10-254 Olsztyn', NULL, '543563663'),
    (5, 'Renard', 'Piotrowski', '47022596157', 'ul. Kochanowskiego Jana 79 60-846 Poznań', 'RenardPiotrowski@armyspy.com', '353526728'),
    (6, 'Walerian', 'Tomaszewski', '87060703054', 'ul. Mandarynkowa 133 61-602 Poznań', 'WalerianTomaszewski@teleworm.us', '352363677'),
    (7, 'Aleksander', 'Borkowski', '75091956093', 'ul. Szkolna 60 18-214 Klukowo', 'AleksanderBorkowski@armyspy.com', '534563667'),
    (8, 'Kasper', 'Sawicki', '90021902977', 'ul. Żulińskiego Romana 73 20-706 Lublin', 'KasperSawicki@rhyta.com', '356647783'),
    (9, 'Tadeusz', 'Kowalczyk', '53052962057', 'ul. Kaczeńcowa 112 31-831 Kraków', 'TadeuszKowalczyk@rhyta.com', '543525656'),
    (10, 'Krystyna', 'Wojciechowska', '77102562442', 'ul. Ceramików 41 44-151 Gliwice', 'KrystynaWojciechowska@jourrapide.com', '243242342'),
    (11, 'Drugi', 'Jabłoński', '99083180338', 'ul. Miarki Karola 104 41-400 Mysłowice', 'DrugiJablonski@jourrapide.com', '353453563'),
    (12, 'Klimek', 'Sawicki', '83092785732', 'ul. Lilli Wenedy 34 65-342 Zielona Góra', 'KlimekSawicki@rhyta.com', '423423542'),
    (13, 'Matylda ', 'Król', '33052624966', 'ul. Podwójna 80 03-290 Warszawa', 'MatyldaKrol@teleworm.us', '535352624'),
    (14, 'Mirosława ', 'Maciejewska', '70120496283', 'ul. Starograniczna 60 54-230 Wrocław', 'MiroslawaMaciejewska@armyspy.com', '432524356'),
    (15, 'Jadwiga ', 'Kowalska', '68100129449', 'ul. Pańska 61 00-124 Warszawa', 'JadwigaKowalska@teleworm.us', '534626245'),
    (16, 'Albin ', 'Jasiński', '79061256778', 'ul. Agawy 41 15-583 Białystok', 'AlbinJasinski@jourrapide.com', '313434245'),
    (17, 'Walerian ', 'Wysocki', '55052575592', 'ul. Batorego Stefana 141 41-707 Ruda Śląska', 'WalerianWysocki@dayrep.com', '423425253'),
    (18, 'Rościsława ', 'Grabowska', '46042706081', 'ul. Strzechy 100 43-190 Mikołów', 'RoscislawaGrabowska@rhyta.com', '423542525'),
    (19, 'Salomea ', 'Wieczorek', '81031342846', 'ul. Kościuszki 76 05-500 Piaseczno', 'SalomeaWieczorek@dayrep.com', '425342524'),
    (20, 'Sobiesław ', 'Duda', '75080205579', 'ul. Bogusławskiego Wojciecha 51 20-358 Lublin', 'SobieslawDuda@armyspy.com', '425456345'),
    (21, 'Kaja ', 'Kamińska', '54103141683', 'ul. Chwiałkowskiego Mariana 41 61-571 Poznań', 'KajaKaminska@teleworm.us', '453567584'),
    (22, 'Stefcia ', 'Borkowska', '46121050564', 'ul. Architektów 16 02-395 Warszawa', 'StefciaBorkowska@rhyta.com', '867945765'),
    (25, 'Friderich', 'Wojciechowski', '84061793554', 'ul. Radzymińska 51 15-863 Białystok', 'FriderichWojciechowski@dayrep.com', '354352655'),
    (26, 'Łukasz ', 'Nowicki', '98121922873', 'ul. Saska 141 03-914 Warszawa', 'LukaszNowicki@rhyta.com', '981192283'),
    (27, 'Fryderyka ', 'Walczak', '51122958803', 'ul. Dworcowa 132 78-410 Szczecinek', 'FryderykaWalczak@dayrep.com', '453526275'),
    (28, 'Grzegorz', 'Grabowski', '54072337296', 'ul. Nagietkowa 65 35-604 Rzeszów', NULL, '425252465'),
    (29, 'Fryderyka  ', 'Szczepańska', '43061591043', 'ul. Gdańska 66 85-915 Bydgoszcz', NULL, '565365526'),
    (30, 'Augustyn ', 'Kaczmarek', '60120306631', 'ul. Polskich Marynarzy 131 ul. Polskich Marynarzy 131', 'AugustynKaczmarek@rhyta.com', '637936734'),
    (31, 'Gustaw ', 'Wojciechowski', '69081771050', 'ul. Bluszczowa 75 04-234 Warszawa', 'GustawWojciechowski@armyspy.com', '536277466'),
    (32, 'Albin ', 'Sokołowski', '84061084317', 'ul. Zubrzyckiego Franciszka 66 44-122 Gliwice', 'AlbinSokolowski@dayrep.com', '535263576'),
    (33, 'Przemysław ', 'Kwiatkowski', '90062001853', 'ul. Krzywińska 94 60-114 Poznań', 'PrzemyslawKwiatkowski@teleworm.us', '975768356'),
    (34, 'Wiola ', 'Sokołowska', '33052706020', 'ul. Tarasowa 10 31-998 Kraków', 'WiolaSokolowska@rhyta.com', '854666353'),
    (35, 'Kuba ', 'Nowak', '41092297817', 'ul. Ciepła 29 70-882 Szczecin', 'KubaNowak@dayrep.com', '653674734'),
    (36, 'Amadei ', 'Król', '80100683615', 'Al. Zagłębia Dąbrowskiego 133 41-303 Dąbrowa Górnicza', 'AmadeiKrol@teleworm.us', '784563674'),
    (37, 'Blanka', 'Grabowska', '71112116985', 'ul. Chełmońskiego Józefa 100 42-202 Częstochowa', 'BlankaGrabowska@armyspy.com', '356363454'),
    (38, 'Serafina', 'Czerwinska', '41062111701', 'ul. Kminkowa 88 20-225 Lublin', 'SerafinaCzerwinska@dayrep.com', '435436453'),
    (39, 'Lubomierz ', 'Michalski', '71011263777', 'ul. Wiśniowa 95 44-330 Jastrzębie-Zdrój', 'LubomierzMichalski@teleworm.us', '543636345'),
    (40, 'Zygmunt ', 'Pawłowski', '91081324372', 'ul. Płowce 36 75-805 Koszalin', 'ZygmuntPawlowski@teleworm.us', '645636535');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `klienci` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

Code nie_obslugiwani

```
INSERT INTO `nie_obsługiwany` (`powod`, `od_kiedy`, `do_kiedy`, `status`, `klienci_id_klienta`) VALUES
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2017-09-20', NULL, 'cofnięte', 1),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2014-01-08', NULL, 'cofnięte', 2),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2017-02-08', NULL, 'cofnięte', 3),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-06-08', NULL, 'cofnięte', 4),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-03-03', NULL, 'cofnięte', 5),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2016-02-05', NULL, 'cofnięte', 6),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-02-02', NULL, 'cofnięte', 7),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2016-02-08', NULL, 'cofnięte', 8),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2017-05-15', NULL, 'cofnięte', 9),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2017-06-04', NULL, 'cofnięte', 10),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-10-05', NULL, 'cofnięte', 11),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-02-08', NULL, 'cofnięte', 12),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-02-17', NULL, 'cofnięte', 13),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-02-08', NULL, 'cofnięte', 14),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-02-03', NULL, 'na stałe', 2),
    ('brak zaplaty za zamówienie', '2018-02-02', NULL, 'na stałe', 1);
```

Expected information:
[Expected data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AXiX.png)

Comment: I think your query is wrong. Can you dump your some part of database here?

Comment: do you have sample data to share with us? what are you trying to do? what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap `USE` and `DELIMITER` commands at the beginning, and second: append the delimiter `//` at the end of the procedure (after the `END` keyword and before the last `DELIMITER`):

```
USE kwiaciarnia
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE  klienci_nie_obslugiwani (IN p1 varchar(30))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM klienci, nie_obslugiwany
WHERE klienci.id_klienta = nie_obslugiwany.klienci_id_klienta AND nie_obslugiwany.`status`= p1;
END
//
delimiter ;
```